# Unable to get token info on solana main net

Tags: javascript, cryptography, solana

I am getting this weird error `TokenAccountNotFoundError` which means that the token is invalid but i can literally look at it from the solana explorer. This happens when i am trying with the address on main net of my token and when i try it with the address of a dummy token on the devnet the system works flawlessly .  Here is everything
https://sourceb.in/Sk7Kr0IMvS

https://explorer.solana.com/address/ptX2XE63jdoA3x9tX1SUgVQpBStgi2516Q4xKR5pWq4

Comment: it would be great if you can add the complete error log here that'll be helpful to understand the issue clearly.

Comment: @Arjun The stack traces are leading only to the package I have narrowed it down to the first spl.getTokenAccount... call

Comment: I would still recommend that if you share the complete error log that will be helpful and also the code @ https://sourceb.in/Sk7Kr0IMvS is also not in working state. So can't help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Arjun the bin is accessible

Comment: @arnav it's accessible but not in has lot of issues, when I tried to run on my end it's just full of issues. Can you provide working script from where I can kick off. If you try to run code you provided, it's not working. Please also mention web3.js version you are using.

Comment: @arnav I think I got your issue. If you can provide minimal `WORKING` code. I can be sure.

Comment: That code works when I am on devnet and change the token accordingly. What exactly do you want me to provide? I am not sure @Arjun

Comment: I am using the latest 0.2.0